# How to get yii2 clicked radioList value in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, yii2

I have this in my form

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'system_user')->inline(true)->radioList(["Yes"=>"Yes","No"=>"No"],['onClick'=>'getValue($(this).val());','id'=>'system_user']) ?>
```

and I need to get the value of clicked radio button in Jquery/javascript, and I have implimented this

```
<script>
function getValue($value){
        alert($value);
    }
</script>
```

But it gives empty alert. Any one to assist please, I have stacked for a day now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add  an event  manager fur input:radio

```
  $("input:radio[name='your_field_name']:checked").val();
```

and for yii2

```
$("input:radio[name='modelName[fieldName]']:checked").val();
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my time, and the name in yii2 activeForm I had to write ```name = modelName[fieldName]```

Comment: @Roman   correct  .. answer  updated with a proper fieldname